# Why is my map not initializing after receiving location permission?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, fusedlocationproviderclient

The first time a user opens my MapsActivity they are asked for location permission. It should then start my satellite view map with markers at different locations. However, it opens a generic google maps without my markers, but if you then exit the activity and start it again once location permissions have already been granted, it works fine. I'm pretty sure it's not calling my initMap() function and hence not calling the onMapReady(GoogleMap, googleMap) function where the map is set to satellite view and the markers are added. I'm pretty sure that in my onRequestPermissionsResult() function it is not calling the initMap() function when it should, but I don't know why?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mMap = googleMap;
        Log.d("map", mMap.toString());
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {
            Log.d("map", "location permission granted");
            getDeviceLocation();
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            this.mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
            init();
        }
        myReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("garbageSpots");
        myReference.addValueEventListener(stateValueEventListener4 = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot children : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    LatLng coords = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(children.child("lat").getValue().toString()), Double.parseDouble(children.child("long").getValue().toString()));
                    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().title(children.getKey()).position(coords);
                    mMap.addMarker(options);
                    Log.d("map", "marker for loop");
                }
                Log.d("map", "end of mk for loop");
                myReference.removeEventListener(stateValueEventListener4);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, InfoWindowActivity.class);
                LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
                String title = marker.getTitle();
                i.putExtra("location", latLng);
                i.putExtra("title", title);
                startActivity(i);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;
    private DatabaseReference myReference;
    private ValueEventListener stateValueEventListener4;
    private EditText mSearchText;
    private ImageView mGps;
    private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        mSearchText = findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        mGps = findViewById(R.id.ic_gps);
        Log.d("map", "onCreate");
        getLocationPermission();
    }

    private void init(){
        Log.d("map", "init now");
        mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                    Log.d("map", "actionId in init");
                    geoLocate();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
        mGps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getDeviceLocation();
            }
        });

        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    private void geoLocate() {
        Log.d("map", "geoLocate start");
        String searchString = mSearchText.getText().toString();
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
        List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.d("map", "geoLocate catch error");
        }

        if(list.size() > 0){
            Address address = list.get(0);
            moveCamera(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                    address.getAddressLine(0));
        }
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MapsActivity.this);
        try{
            if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){
                final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                Log.d("map", "GDL mLPG");
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        Log.d("map", "GDL on complete");
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d("map", "GDL on success");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location)task.getResult();
                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                    DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                                    "My Location");
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.d("map", "getDeviceLocation catch error");
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, String title){
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
        if(!title.equals("My Location")){
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(title);
            mMap.addMarker(options);
        }
        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    private void initMap(){
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        Log.d("map", mapFragment + " initMap");
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d("map", "getLocationPermission start");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.d("map", "first if");
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Log.d("map", "second if");
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                Log.d("map", mLocationPermissionsGranted.toString() + " mLPG string");
                initMap();
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        permissions,
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                Log.d("map", "second if failed");
            }
        }else{
            Log.d("map", "first if failed");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            Log.d("map", String.valueOf(LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) + " location permission request code");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d("map", "ORPR");
        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            Log.d("map", String.valueOf(grantResults[i]));
                            Log.d("map", "false permission");
                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                    Log.d("map", "initORPR");
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my log

```
2020-11-23 13:21:58.862 30494-30494/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp D/map: onCreate
2020-11-23 13:21:58.862 30494-30494/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp D/map: getLocationPermission start
2020-11-23 13:21:58.863 30494-30494/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp D/map: first if failed
2020-11-23 13:21:58.896 30494-30494/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp D/map: 1234 location permission request code
2020-11-23 13:21:58.926 30494-30494/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp D/ViewRootImpl@42a73ef[MapsActivity]: setView = DecorView@f405efc[MapsActivity] TM=true MM=false
2020-11-23 13:21:58.993 30494-30494/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp D/ViewRootImpl@42a73ef[MapsActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2020-11-23 13:21:59.049 30494-30494/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp D/ViewRootImpl@42a73ef[MapsActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 486528770048} changed=true
2020-11-23 13:21:59.244 30494-30494/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp D/ViewRootImpl@42a73ef[MapsActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
2020-11-23 13:21:59.244 30494-30494/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp D/ViewRootImpl@42a73ef[MapsActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
2020-11-23 13:21:59.280 30494-30494/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp D/ViewRootImpl@42a73ef[MapsActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
2020-11-23 13:22:04.836 30494-30499/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 6MB to compile void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.c(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10)
2020-11-23 13:22:12.289 30494-30494/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp D/ViewRootImpl@42a73ef[MapsActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
2020-11-23 13:22:12.353 30494-30494/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp D/map: ORPR
2020-11-23 13:22:12.353 30494-30494/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp D/map: -1
2020-11-23 13:22:12.353 30494-30494/com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp D/map: false permission
```

Here is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.garbagespots.garbagespotsapp">
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".InstructionsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomePage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".PictureActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".InfoWindowActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ReportActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".InfoWindowActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CleanedUpActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".InfoWindowActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".InfoWindowActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MapsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignupActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SpotAdderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_spot_adder"
            android:parentActivityName=".MapsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomePage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomePage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:parentActivityName=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAF4V4wLa4OioU_taKsh59BfTVs1i02vgA" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
            android:parentActivityName=".InstructionsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please show your Manifest

Comment: I added it @SarahKhan

Comment: Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, where is this in your manifest?

Comment: The [tag:google-maps-api-3] tag is for the JS API v3. Removing this from your question. In the future, please make sure you use appropriate tags for your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

to my Manifest and it worked